# Most appropriate way to return all funds in contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Let's say there is a contract with a function to return the funds back to an owner address after some modifiers are valid.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.1

contract example{
    uint64 public contractTime;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        contractTime = uint64(block.timestamp) + 31556926;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier expiredContract {
        require(block.timestamp >= contractTime);
        _;
    }

    function returnToOwner() public payable onlyOwner expiredContract {
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance); // Is there a better way to do this?
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to empty out the contract funds to the owner address? Or is this the "standard" way of doing it?

Comment: You can use selfdestruct(), which is also explained here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/315/why-are-selfdestructs-used-in-contract-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging you can simply use `selfdestruct()` for returning all funds to contract creator.